# printing label at specific position

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have 11 inch X 8.5 inch paper to print labels. The paper is divided into two columns i.e 4.25 width of each column containing 11 labels in each.

So, Size of each label is `1 inch X 4.25 inch`.

Now my Question is: I'm using Northwind DB in MS Access 2010, in that considering the table dbo_Products, I want to print **Product ID** and **Product Name** on each label.

I could join the label report to form but i couldn't get output.

As said earlier The sheet contains two columns, if user wants to print label on specific label position it should be able to print on that.

(Ex. User wants to print **Product ID: 10** on the **position 5**, the corresponding product info must be print on the label located on the 5th position of the page. (the positioning of labels on the page is shown below)

```
1     |     2 

3     |     4

5     |     6

7     |     8

...... till 22
```

It would be great if anyone could help me out in this issue by showing the connectivity between the form to label and print it in specific label place.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you @Omar for editing. Hope i get suitable solution for this.

Comment: Are you using plain paper? I'm unaware of a two column 4.25" width adhesive label. Labels are typically designed to print from the first to the last, starting at the upper left label on the sheet. Are you saying you want the user to have the ability to select any given 'label' on a sheet to print on? If so, that will take some special code to handle.

Comment: Yes I want the user to have ability to print on a label of his choice on the adhesive label paper of given dimensions. you understood my question correct. @WayneG.Dunn. Hope i get a solution for this.

Comment: Take a look at this link and see if it meets your needs... http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-start-an-access-label-report-with-any-label-on-the-sheet/

Comment: Thank you for the link @WayneG.Dunn. It served me to understand the how to start. that link specifies of creation of blank labels and then printing them. but i needed to print specific field data in the specified label. Ex. user wants to print Customers details from Id's 3-6 in the labels positioned 4-7, then how to do that code. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How comfortable are you with Access and VBA? The solution mentioned should work for what you want it to do unless I don't understand all you are asking. That solution will print whatever you desire to print (by selection query) and start in the label position you specify. Are your labels blank to start with? I could write the code, but before I do, I would want to understand EXACTLY what you want. Please share what you have done for your selection query and your form.

Comment: I just followed the instructions on that site and created code/form/table that allows me to start printing on any label I choose. Let me know if you want it.

Comment: Im a beginner in MS Access and VBA, learning how to do things. I need to print on empty label sheet to start with and then later prints should be done on the desired label to start. it would be great If i can get help, I ll also try again for solution. Your help would be appreciated, Thank you @WayneG.Dunn

Comment: Yep I got it. Thank you for the support. But if user wants to print only certain rows in the table, i.e print costumerID 1 to 10 in labels 5-15 then how can we do that to print specific IDs in Specified labels ? Thank you @WayneG.Dunn

Comment: Using the code you have, then add a 'WHERE' clause to the DoCmd.RunSQL query syntax to select only the records you want to print.

Comment: if My form has two text boxes: 1. to enter which ID has to be printed 
2. To enter on which label it has to be printed, then how can i perform operation? @WayneG.Dunn

Comment: Do you plan to allow the user to print only one label, or will they always print a range of labels? Add a third textbox to your form so that you have: (1) Which Label to Print On; (2) Starting identifier to print; (3) Ending identifier to print. Then have your VBA code use the starting/ending textbox values in your 'WHERE' clause.

Comment: Exactly, That is what I wanted to do. Can you help me with the code to use the text boxes, i'm unable to get output, shows error code. I've used the same constrains till now as mentioned in the link you gave.

Comment: where and what to insert the DoCmd.RunSQL code ... sorry i didnt mention that above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the instructions found at http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-start-an-access-label-report-with-any-label-on-the-sheet/

Next I modified that to have three textboxes instead of one. They are named 'txtStart', 'txtEnd', 'txtLabelPos'. Use the code below for that form.

Note the 'WHERE' clause in the SQL... change the tables / field names to suit your own needs.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit


Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    'Reset and take no further action.
    Me!txtStart.Value = 1
End Sub



Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
'Pass table with label data, position for first label, and label report.

Dim bytPosition As Variant
Dim bytCounter As Byte
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

If IsNull(Me.txtStart) Or Me.txtStart = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a starting range for the data.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Start Range"
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtEnd) Or Me.txtEnd = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter an ending range for the data.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing End Range"
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtLabelPos) Or Me.txtLabelPos = "" Or Not IsNumeric(Me.txtLabelPos) Then
    MsgBox "You must enter the starting label position to print on.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Label Position"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set rst.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM tblCustomerLabels" _
        , , adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

'Delete previous label data.
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tblCustomerLabels"

'Add one empty record for each missing label.
bytPosition = Nz(Me!txtLabelPos.Value, 0)

For bytCounter = 2 To bytPosition
    rst.AddNew
    rst.Update
Next

'Update label data.
Dim strSQL  As String
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblCustomerLabels ( Company, [Last Name], [First Name], Address, City, [State/Province], [ZIP/Postal Code], [Country/Region] ) " & _
            "SELECT Customers.Company, Customers.[Last Name], Customers.[First Name], Customers.Address, Customers.City, Customers.[State/Province], Customers.[ZIP/Postal Code], Customers.[Country/Region] " & _
            "FROM Customers " & _
            "Where [Last Name] >= '" & Me.txtStart & "' AND [Last Name] <= '" & Me.txtEnd & "';"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

'Open label report.
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptCustomerLabels", acViewPreview

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

Exit Sub

errHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```